# Attaching event listeners to DOM instead of polluting global namespace

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am totally stuck in this particular situation for last 2 days and have read 100's of articles but couldn't help.

My html page has many elements (or consider these elements as widgets) and number of these elements on the page is dynamic. Same element can be repeated too (multiple number of times). So for convenience I have not given any id to them. lets say these elements are

A1
A2
B1
B2
B3
.
.
.

Now events keep happening on the page. And what I want is that each of these elements should be able to subscribe to multiple events, keep a log of all the changes happened so far and change themselves in a particular fashion depending on that event.

lets say an event lionAttacked is raised and B3 has subscribed for this event. Now if there had been some id of B3, lets say 332124, then my code to do it would be

```
    document.addEventListener("lionAttacked", function(e){
            document.getElementById('332124').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById('332124').innerHTML + "Lion attacked us;"; 
    });
```

But since there is no id of B3 so ideally what I would want is something like following

```
<div onload="
            document.addEventListener('lionAttacked', function(e){
            /*do whatever you want to do with your element when lion attacks*/
            this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML + 'Lion attacked us;';});

             document.addEventListener('wolfArrived', function(e){
            /*do whatever you want to do with your element when wolf arrives*/
            this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML + 'Wolf came to visit us;';});

            "> 
    my element 
</div>
```

For me this will be more encapsulated kind of code ie all the logic related to element resides within it.

Any help is really appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object that contains all the event subscriptions. The keys are the event names, and the value is an array of all the elements that have subscribed.

```
var subscriptions = {};

function subscribe(event, element) {
    if (!subscriptions[event]) {
        subscriptions[event] = [];
    }
    subscriptions[event].push(element);
}
```

Then the code for the event listener would loop through all the elements in the array.

```
document.addEventListener("lionAttacked", function(e) {
    if (subscriptions[event]) {
        subscriptions[event].forEach(function (el) {
            el.innerHTML += "Lion attacked us";
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: who will call subscribe and when. I thought I should call this at the time of element/widget load something similar to this onload="subscribe('lionAttacked',this)" but onload is not defined for html elements

Comment: That's up to the design of the application. From the question, I assumed you already had the subscription model designed, you just didn't know how to make it work. If the elements are created dynamically, the code that creates them should call `subscribe()`.

Comment: You could put attributes in them, like `data-subscriber="lionAttacked"`, and then use `document.querySelectorAll('[data-subscriber]')` to find them and call `subscribe()` on each of them.

Comment: elements comes as part of page itself. There is no client side code that create them. Its just that number of such elements isn't fixed. Moreover all the elements who are subscribing to the event "lionAttacked" may not be doing same thing when the event "lionAttacked" is raised. Considering there can be many events and many subscribers, I am looking for a way by which I encapsulate the code to subscribe for any event within the element itself without polluting global namespace

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect. You need to do something to tell the software which elements are subscribing to which events. Something analogous to the way you would use `addEventListener` for normal event binding. Are you trying to do something like the way you could use `onclick=xxx` to bind a click handler? Those event handlers are built into the browser, I don't think they can be extended to user-defined events.